# Getting the sum of numbers in a resultset column

Tags: php

I have this code below that displays a database result set.

```
<?php foreach ($_SESSION['merged_data'] as $data){ ?>
 <tr>
 <td><label><?php echo $data['sales_day']; ?></label></td>
<td><label><?php echo $data['sales_total']; ?></label></td>
<td><label><?php echo $data['sales_comm']; ?></label></td>
```

The above code is working fine. Then i try to calculate the sum of all the values of the the column sales_comm with the following code

```
<div class = "col-sm-3"> <?php $comm_total += $data['sales_comm'];
echo $comm_total; ?>
```

Problem is that instead of returning the sum of values of $sales_comm, it returns the last value.

Comment: Where did you define `$comm_total`? Please show us your full code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the addition in the loop and then the output after the loop is completed. If you are going to use `+=` you also have to initialise the counter to zero be fore the loop.

```
<?php 
$comm_total = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['merged_data'] as $data){ 
    $comm_total += $data['sales_comm'];
?>
    <tr>
        <td><label><?php echo $data['sales_day']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $data['sales_total']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $data['sales_comm']; ?></label></td>
    </tr>

<?php
} // endforeach
?>
</table>
<div class="col-sm-3"> <?php echo $comm_total; ?> </div>
```